# How to add “List-Unsubscribe” in email header using CakeEmail component

Tags: cakephp, gmail, cakephp-2.3

I've tried the below, but it didn't works in gmail

```
$email = new CakeEmail();
$email->addHeaders(array("List-Unsubscribe"=>"<$url>"));
```

Any suggestion? Thank you

Comment: maybe $email->header(array('List-Unsubscribe' => $url));

Comment: What explicitly doesn't work? Does it fail with a PHP error? Does the raw email header not show the "List-Unsubscribe"?

Comment: no it can see in the email header, but it i don't get the "unsubscribe" link in gmail next the sender email.